# Error in SeleniumLibrary.Input Text - used in if/else block

Tags: selenium, variables, robotframework

I have a problem with RobotFramework code. Im trying to make an If/ELSE and testing some functionalities but when I declare the Keyword I get the error: 
"Keyword 'SeleniumLibrary.Input Text' expected 2 arguments, got 10."

I tried changing the variables of the Keywords but nothing.

```
*** Settings ***
Library           SeleniumLibrary

*** Variables ***
${WEB}            https://google.es    #Url we are going to open
${BROWSER}        chrome    #Browser to use
${SELENIUM_DELAY}    1

*** Test Cases ***
Conditional Test    q    Different from 0    Equal to 0

*** Keywords ***
Open Browser
    Log To Console    Opening browser...
    Open Browser    ${WEB}    ${BROWSER}
    Maximize Browser Window

Conditional Test
    [Arguments]    ${textview}    ${text}    ${text2}
    Open Browser
    Input Text    ${textview}    ${text}    if    ${SELENIUM_DELAY}    !=    0
    ...    ELSE    Input Text    ${textview}    ${text2}
```

I just tried to make a condition that if the value of ${SELENIUM_DELAY} is different from 0, then write on google search a String.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax for conditional execution is different, you have to use the keyword `Run Keyword If`, providing the keywords to run when the condition is true/false (the false is optional). Like this:

```
Run Keyword If    ${SELENIUM_DELAY} != 0    Input Text    ${textview}    ${text}
    ...    ELSE    Input Text    ${textview}    ${text2}
```